# Deploying ASP.NET with SQL Server Express on Windows authentication

Tags: iis, deployment

I am deploying an ASP.NET application that has a SQL Server Express database (running on Windows authentication) on the same machine where it is deployed. But I am unable to connect to database when the website is deployed on IIS.

I am not sure if I am missing anything here. It is the first time I am deploying an application with database.

My connection string is as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="MyAppConnectionString" 
        connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyAppDB;Integrated Security=True;" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />   
</connectionStrings>
```